# get the last ID after insert in mysql

Tags: mysql

how can i get the ID of the last insert statement

im using trigger to create a ID for every record

```
INSERT INTO table1_seqdocument VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.tracknum = CONCAT('DOC', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
```

and i need that ID for other table

this is this my insert statement

```
INSERT INTO tble_transaction
  (
      tracknum 
     ,signatoryid
     ,signed
     ,status
     ,signatorylevel
  )
  VALUES 
     (?,?,?,?,? )
```

what i want is to retrieve the ID and use it for another insert statement but using other table. is it possible? thank you

Comment: Please show the complete create trigger statement. Is it on  `tble_transaction`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Your code as you posted it, works fine: see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aaee/1). Please provide the `create table` and `create trigger` statements to see what could be wrong. Have you defined the primary key and auto_increment?

Comment: Using a database internal as some kind of meaningful value beyond the scope of the database is just asking for trouble. Rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @@identity

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS [@@IDENTITY];
```

Answer (score 0):

LAST_INSERT_ID() can only tell you the ID of the most recently auto-generated ID for that entire database connection, not for each individual table, which is also why the query should only read SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() - without specifying a table. As soon as you fire off another INSERT query on that connection, it gets overwritten. If you want the generated ID when you insert to some table, you must run SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() immediately after doing that (or use some API function which does this for you).

If you want the newest ID currently in an arbitrary table, you have to do a SELECT MAX(id) on that table, where id is the name of your ID column. However, this is not necessarily the most recently generated ID, in case that row has been deleted, nor is it necessarily one generated from your connection, in case another connection manages to perform an INSERT between your own INSERT and your selection of the ID.

(For the record, your query actually returns N rows containing the most recently generated ID on that database connection, where N is the number of rows in table1.)

Comment: The Asker already is using `LAST_USER_ID()` right after a single insert. I would not even suggest to do `select max(id)`. And how does your last line relate to the question? There is no query of N rows in the question, nor a table1.